# Way to prevent stdout.readline() from freezing program

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

In my current program, I start a server using subprocess.Popen() and continue reading from the stdout using readline(). However, when it gets stuck on readline until a new line appears. This is bad because I need to be able to execute other code while waiting for the server to output. Is there a way I can stop this from occurring?

```py
import subprocess

server = subprocess.Popen("startup command", stdout= subprocess.PIPE, encoding= "utf-8")

while True:
    out = server.stdout.readline()
    if out != "":
        print(out)
    print("checked for line")
```

i would prefer to avoid having to multi-thread because different parts of my code would no longer be thread-safe.

Comment: You have to use threading.  Thread-safety is usually not a big problem in Python because of the GIL.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing. You can still get interleaving with the GIL. Setting up a `threading.Queue` is pretty simple and allows for easy communication.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to get threads involved; they will only complicate your program at this point. If simply polling isn't a reasonable option, use one of the async libraries (there are several and it's easy in all of them). Remember that file descriptors piped to a subprocess are really no different than any other file descriptor; the only reason it is handled specially is so you can also track the exit code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use threading as @tim Roberts said. What you'll need to do is have your read loop post events to the main thread. Whether that is with global flags or a queue. Take a look at the documentation for queue.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `poll()` and `communicate()` instead:

```py
import subprocess
import time

with subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'sleep 1 && echo OK'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    while proc.poll() is None:
        print('<doing something useful>')
        time.sleep(0.3)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    print(out)
```

```
<doing something useful>
<doing something useful>
<doing something useful>
<doing something useful>
b'OK\n'
```

Comment: I don't think this will help OP's problem, since it sounds like they want to interleave reading and working. Remember `Popen.poll` is not the normal file descriptor `poll`.

Comment: TBH, the whole problem could be solved by just [reading asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯